# Delphi and code completion during debug

Tags: delphi, debugging

When I run/debug my project the code completion doesn't work. Is it possible to use code completion during debug/run?

Answer (score 3):

Code completion 'handles' such as ctrl+click and mouse-hover-over are replaced with 'variable inspection tools' when debugging, but ctrl+space still works I think (at least in the Delphi 7 I'm still using.) Delphi 7 also allows multiple instances to be open, and I find the auto-update of the editor works well, so you could use one instance to debug, and one to edit (with code completion). You only need to stop debugging in the one instance to be able to compile/build with the other.

Comment: With Delphi 5/6, ctrl+space = code insight, and that nicely displays a little box saying "Code Insight(tm) features are disabled during debugging".

Comment: It seems code-completion is not completely functional in Modern Delphi versions (2009,2010,XE,Xe2,..) either, during debug.